# jpa multiple bidirectional many to one relationship to the same field

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, replace

I have a problem i hope someone can help me solving.

My system has got an entity "Product". On a product it should be possible to set "replacement products" (products that are supposed to be sold instead of the original product). We have two types of replacement. On a product, i need to be able to set either none, one of them or both types of replacement product. But, only one product should be set per type. In addition to this, i want to be able to look at a product and get a list of other products that has this product as their replacement product.

Short version:

- Product -> replacement (two types, one of each)
- Product -> list of
  products that it replaces (of both types of replacement)

My solution this far has been to create an abstract class ReplacementProduct with subclasses(one for each replacement type), with discriminatorvalues. 
The replacementproduct table in the database has the following fields: 
id, replacementproduct, replacementType

Further, i have placed two fields on the Product entity (instances of the subclasses for replacement types). Like this i have obtained a one way link from product to another product with a replacement type.

My problem is to make this link go both ways. As I said, I want to be able to get a list of products with the Product in question as their replacement product.

Is this possible without using a lot of java logic?

I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bidirectional ManyToMany is needed between products.  The owning side would setup a mapkey mapping, using the type as the key.  The other side doesn't need a key, and would reflect all the products it can replace.
This is described here 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Map_Key_Columns_.28JPA_2.0.29